# Why doesn't my `Runnable` have a `start` method?

Tags: java, multithreading, inheritance, interface, inner-classes

Why is it that i must extend `Thread` in an inner class instead of implementing `Runnable`
The following code works:-

```
class Outer{

 Inner innerObj;

 Outer(){
  innerObj = new Inner();
 }

 public void begin(){

  innerObj.start();
 }

 class Inner extends Thread{

  Inner(){
   System.out.println("Thread initialized!");
  }

  public void run(){

    System.out.println("Thread running!");

  }  
 }
}

class Driver{

 public static void main(String[] args){

  Outer o1 = new Outer();
  o1.begin();

 }

}
```

However using a `Runnable` causes a compile error:-

```
class Outer{

 Inner innerObj;

 Outer(){
  innerObj = new Inner();
 }

 public void begin(){

  innerObj.start();
 }

 class Inner implements Runnable{

  Inner(){
   System.out.println("Thread initialized!");
  }

  public void run(){

    System.out.println("Thread running!");

  }  
 }
}

class Driver{

 public static void main(String[] args){

  Outer o1 = new Outer();
  o1.begin();

 }

}
```

Comment: Runnable-interface has no method start()

Comment: We all know what the error was in this case, but generally, part of Asking Technical Questions 101 is when you say something causes an error, **quote the error message**. In this case, it should have been blatantly obvious: `Method start not found on class Inner` or similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because implementing `Runnable` doesn't give a class the `start` method. You will need to create a `Thread` to run the `Inner`.

```
Inner i = new Inner();
Thread t = new Thread( i );
```

Answer (score 1):

Runnable doesn't provide a start() method . You actually need to create a Thread to run the Inner class